# Replace an existing object with a new one in the same place in memory

Tags: c#, object-pooling

In C# it is possible to pool existing objects in an [ObjectPool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.objectpool.objectpool-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0). But this only works for reference types that provide a method to reset the object to some well defined initial state. For example a type may implement [IResettable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.objectpool.iresettable?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0) interface or provide a method that mirrors its constructor.

I wonder if it would be possible to pool any arbitrary reference type. The steps would be the following:

- Call `ObjectPool<T>.Get()` to get an instance.
- Replace the memory pointed to by the recovered instance with a new fresh instance.
- Use the new object and return it to the pool when done.

The question is if it is at all possible to achieve point 2. Theoretically it should be possible. I am, however, not sure if it is possible in C#. From what I understand the new keyword will always create an instance at an unoccupied "slot" in the managed heap. What would be needed for this to work is a way to create a new object at a specified memory location. Furthermore, one would need to make sure that the old object was disposed of, hoping that disposal is enough and call to the finalizer is not needed.

Comment: what is wrong with implementing `IResettable` ? what you wana store in your object ? Why you wana reuse memory?

Comment: Nothing is wrong in implementing `IResettable` other than when the type in question is a .NET type so I can't implement it. `PipeReader` for example. I want to reuse memory to limit GC pressure because I am trying to achieve as deterministic results as possible. A GC collection may halt execution at any point in time. In an application used for hardware testing such halt may mean that a message to the hardware may be sent later than it could hence producing less accurate result.

Comment: if you have fx 4 members which are also reference type object would only take size of this 4 pointer + some const size per object ... I do not see ObjectPool usefull here ... only if you would have large value type members count or large arrays of them then you can just set values to default in  IResettable (edit: strings as members would be nasty)

Comment: This is not much and it probably wouldn't make much of a difference but it would just be nice if it would be possible. I don't really get why we can't store actual instance of a reference type on the stack in an unsafe block.

Comment: because of polymorphism ? again example of class with 4 other reference type as members ... they are stored as , well, references ... struct/value type has well known size

Comment: Fair point but when you want to store the output of a constructor on the stack there is no polymorphism problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only way to achieve that is to let the user of the pool get a `PoolElement<T>`  instead of a instance of `T`. And make sure he access the instance through the `PoolElement`. Which you cant guarantee.

I wouldn't recommend this approach.

There are better ways, pub/sub for example.

Comment: What is PoolElement? Quick google search didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I ment that your Pool returns a custom type PoolElement that wraps the instance. This is a anti-pattern. Dont do it.

Comment: This would still mean that a new instance of the actual type is created. This misses the goal of my question.

Comment: Yes, C# does not support what you want todo. And for good reasons. Its a anti pattern. In fact C# tries to make you lock down your references as much as possible. For example with readonly keyword.